# How to initialize my struct describing RGBA color

Tags: c++, qt

I have a question about structures in c++. How should I declare

> struct color_rgba

in this class? Just I get error:

```
no matching function for call to 'color_rgba::color_rgba()'
```

when I'm trying to do smth with this struct

Child_rectangle_dialog.cpp

```cpp
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "color.h"

class Child_rectangle_dialog : public QDialog
{
private:
    QLineEdit *cords_1, *cords_2;
    Image* our_im;
    QCheckBox* check_box_for_fill;
    //struct color_rgba rectangle_color; ////here
};
```

color.h

```cpp
struct color_rgba
{
    unsigned char r, g, b, a;
    color_rgba(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b, unsigned char a);
};
```

color.cpp

```cpp
#include "color.h"

color_rgb::color_rgb(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b)
{
    this->r = r; this->g = g; this->b = b;
}
color_rgba::color_rgba(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b, unsigned char a)
{
    this->r = r; this->g = g; this->b = b; this->a = a;
}
```

I can't imagine why I get this error cos I'm green hand in c++ and I came here from C.

Comment: How is the structure `color_rgba` used?

Comment: You need to initialize it in your `Child_rectangle_dialog`s constructor, or provide a default constructor.

Comment: I wanted to set colors inside the struct just by calling the constructor

Comment: You have a constructor that takes parameters for `color_rgba` but no default constructor (i.e. one that takes no parameters)

Comment: So, I need another constructor in this class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The struct declares a constructor, so you have to call that constructor when constructing the property `Child_rectangle_dialog::rectangle color`.

Also, your constructor is weird and unnecesary - I will describe below. Consider this instead:

```
class Child_rectangle_dialog : public QDialog
{
private:
    QLineEdit *cords_1, *cords_2;
    Image* our_im;
    QCheckBox* check_box_for_fill;
    struct color_rgba rectangle_color{0, 64, 255, 255};
};
```

### `color.h`

```
struct color_rgba
{
    unsigned char r, g, b, a;
};
```

This will work just fine. Also note that since you're using Qt, Qt has their color type already: [**`QColor`**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html)

### Why is the constructor weird?

In C++, you can initialize the members before the constructor body, and you can do this in header file normally:

```
struct color_rgba 
{
  // This constructor sets alpha to default of 255
  color_rgba(unsigned char red, unsigned char green, unsigned char blue, unsigned char alpha=255)
    : r(red)
    , g(green)
    , b(blue)
    , a(alpha)
  { /* body of the constructor */ }
  unsigned char r, g, b, a;
}
```

In the code above, alpha has a default value, so if you do:

```
color_rgba c(255,0,0);
```

It will compile and `c.a` will be `255`.

You also don't need to use `this->property`. Just use `property` in C++ classes.

### Converting from `QColor`

To convert from `QColor` to `color_rgba`, you can use the constructor again:

```
rectangle_color = color_rgba(color.red(), color.green(), color.blue(), color.alpha());
```

Or, you can be cool and create another constructor:

```
// You could also forward define QColor, but let's keep it simple :)
#include <QColor>

struct color_rgba 
{
  // omitting previous members for brevity
     ...
  // Your new constructor:
  color_rgba(const QColor& qc) 
    : r(qc.red())
    , g(qc.green())
    , b(qc.blue())
    , a(qc.alpha())
  {}
}
```

With that, you can just do:

```
QColor something = ...;
rectangle_color = something;
```

### Converting back

You can also design your struct to convert to qcolor automatically:

```
struct color_rgba 
{
  // omitting previous members for brevity
     ...
  // Operator for QColor conversion
  operator QColor() const { return QColor(r, g, b, a); }
  
}
```

Then you can assign to qcolor:

```
QColor test = rectangle_color;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! By the way, what I should do if I wand to set colors in class method like that:
`void Child_rectangle_dialog::show_color_list()
{
    QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor(Qt::white, this);
    rectangle_color(color.red(), color.green(), color.blue(), color.alpha());
}`

Comment: @gr_new Could you clarify? I don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: I just want to fill this struct fields in class method. Not in color.h

Comment: I wanna call constructor in method and declare struct like: `struct color_rgba rectangle_color;`(sorry for my Englis))

Comment: @gr_new Check my updated answer, but please keep in mind that normally, you should have one question per post. But since you're a newbie and this is a simple thing, I added it to the answer to save you some trouble.

Comment: If you need more help, I created a chat room for you: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231316/struct-object-in-class